# Gitlab filesystemuser messed up

Tags: git, users, gitlab

I have inherited a server with an installed GitLab, but it is unable to run. After a few lookarounds, I've found, it might had a user who got deleted, and the original user to run gitlab was him. I say this, because I have the following:

```
0 ✓ gitlab-mycompany ~ $ ls -lah /var/log/
drwxr-xr-x. 20    994 root   4.0K Jan 15 15:54 gitlab
```

And

```
0 ✓ gitlab-mycompany ~ $ ls -lah /var/log/gitlab/
total 92K
drwxr-xr-x. 20               994 root       4.0K Jan 15 15:54 .
drwxr-xr-x.  8 root              root       4.0K Apr 30 13:53 ..
drwx------.  2 gitlab-prometheus root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 alertmanager
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root              root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 crond
drwx------.  2               994 root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 gitaly
drwx------.  2               994 root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 gitlab-monitor
drwx------.  2               994 root        16K Apr 30 00:28 gitlab-rails
drwx------.  2 git               root       4.0K Apr 30 00:28 gitlab-shell
drwx------.  2               994 root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 gitlab-workhorse
drwx------.  2 root              root       4.0K Jan 15 18:18 logrotate
drwxr-x---.  2 root              gitlab-www 4.0K Apr 30 00:28 nginx
drwx------.  2 gitlab-prometheus root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 node-exporter
drwx------.  2 gitlab-psql       root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 postgres-exporter
drwx------.  2 gitlab-psql       root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 postgresql
drwx------.  2 gitlab-prometheus root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 prometheus
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root              root       4.0K Apr 30 14:03 reconfigure
drwx------.  2 gitlab-redis      root       4.0K Apr 30 13:41 redis
drwx------.  2 gitlab-redis      root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 redis-exporter
drwx------.  2               994 root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 sidekiq
drwx------.  2               994 root       4.0K Apr 30 11:18 unicorn
```

Which user was the 994 in a default installation and what were its privileges?

Answer (score 0):

The ID number might be version or OS-dependent.  On my GitLab system, those files are owned by "git" user, with the same permission flags.  The "git" user primary group was named "git", and it has a different user ID number than yours.

Comment: That is just brilliant. :/ Thanks, I was suspecting the git user too, but that user was not existing with that ID but a different. After fixing that, it worked, tho it had some complications still. Anyhow, thanks again.

Comment: Guess its time to learn how to migrate the data :PYou might want to change your question to be "Which users own files in GitLab installation?"

Comment: The REAL question would be: Who hired that jackass who messed up the old GitLab server. :D Anyhow we will create a brand new installation and migrate only what we need. The rest is gonna go to the backup server.